# How do I stop the Fitbit Surge from storing GPS data?

Tags: privacy, gps, fitbit

I was reading about the privacy of Fitbit devices, and [this Huffington Post article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/mark-weinstein/what-your-fitbit-doesnt-w_b_8851664.html) has a rather concerning point with regard to GPS-enabled fitness trackers:

> In certain cases, the government or legal institution could request your fitness tracker information and then use it against you in a court of law. That’s what happened to Chris Bucchere, a San Francisco cyclist who struck and killed an elderly pedestrian. Bucchere was charged with felony vehicular manslaughter, carrying a potential penalty of six years in prison. Prosecutors obtained his data from his GPS-enabled fitness tracker to show he’d been speeding before the accident. Bucchere’s self-monitoring became a piece of evidence against himself due to a lack of privacy. This is not to condone Bucchere — clearly he committed a crime — rather this just illustrates one example of surprising use cases for what you might think is harmless personal data.

Clearly, I would rather not have my GPS location recorded at all times, in case the data gets hacked or given to anyone without my permission. The [Fitbit Surge](https://www.fitbit.com/uk/surge) is one of these GPS-enabled fitness watches - **how can I disable GPS tracking and clear any information they have on me?** Is the GPS data also synchronised to the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FitBit community, the GPS is only enabled when you have turned on a tracking activity, example, walking, hiking, biking, etc.  From the [Fitbit Community](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Surge/How-do-I-turn-off-the-GPS-on-my-Surge/td-p/940377):

> GPS is only when you are tracking an activity that uses GPS, such as hiking. As soon as you stop tracking that activity GPS is turned off.

and

> By design, it should only turn on when you have started an (outdoor) exercise using the controls on the Surge - that means, Run, Free Run, Walk, Hike, Bike, or Golf. If you haven't started one of those exercises, there wouldn't even be a way of telling if the GPS is on or not.

In other words, to keep the GPS off, just don't run any of those controls.  If you want to have a hike registerd, just put it in "work out" mode and rename it as a hike later.  (From the [FitBit community](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Surge/Turning-Off-GPS-in-Surge/td-p/631317))

Answer (score 2):

This question is likely better asked of FitBit directly through their [help](http://help.fitbit.com) site. Yes, your GPS data is synced to the cloud, because it is retrievable using the FitBit developer's API as described [in their API docs](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/activity/#get-activity-tcx). Accessing it programatically requires a few hoops be jumped through, but disabling this feature and/or deleting stored data is not documented.

FWIW, I've found their email support team to be very responsive when I have questions.